# How to get blank cell from sheet1 to sheet2

Tags: excel

I am trying to get the blank cell value to go from a cell in sheet1 to a cell in sheet2. The problem I first encountered is that it would put zeros for null values and 1/00/00 for dates instead of leaving it blank. Basically I want the cell in sheet2 to be left blank. So I tried an If(ISBLANK() etc...
and it just keeps the text there not even recognizing it as a formula. Here is my code.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A19),"blank",Sheet1!A19)
```

I have tried putting this code in sheet1 cell A19 or sheet2 A1 and same problem.

Comment: It is because there is a formula in sheet 1 A19. Try `=IF(Sheet1!A19="","",Sheet1!A19)`

Comment: Oh thanks Scott that worked